# dragStart starts in the wrong position

Tags: drag-and-drop, libgdx

I'm implementing the drag and drop in Libgdx with DragAndDrop class.
The actors that i have to move are in a grid (Table), centered in the screen.

The drag and drop starts if i click on the top-right corner of the screen, and not if i click on the actor itself! I can't figure out where is the problem.

This grid is a matrix:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Constants.ROWS; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < Constants.COLS; j++) {
            slots[i][j] = new Slot(Item.EMPTY, i, j);
        }
    }
```

Then i use the code above to create the table:

```
public class SlotsAreaActor extends Table {

    public SlotsAreaActor(SlotsArea slotsArea, DragAndDrop dnd) {

        // set the position of this actor in the screen
        setPosition(Constants.SLOTS_AREA_ACTOR_X, Constants.SLOTS_AREA_ACTOR_Y);
        // spaces all the row and the columns
        defaults().space(Constants.ROWS_SPACE);
        row().fill().expandX();

        Slot[][] slots = slotsArea.getSlots();
        for(int i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < slots[0].length; j++) {
                SlotActor slotActor = new SlotActor(slots[i][j]);
                dnd.addSource(new SlotSource(slotActor));
                dnd.addTarget(new SlotTarget(slotActor));
                add(slotActor);
            }

            row();
        }
    }
}
```

In the SlotActor class i set the bounds:

```
x = Constants.APP_WIDTH - Constants.ORIZONTAL_OFFSET - (Constants.TILE_SIZE * (Constants.COLS - slot.getX()));
    y = Constants.APP_HEIGHT - Constants.VERTICAL_OFFSET - (Constants.TILE_SIZE * (Constants.ROWS - slot.getY()));
setBounds(x, y, Constants.TILE_SIZE, Constants.TILE_SIZE);
```

My formulas are wrong someway...

The Slot object holds its x (i, row) in the matrix, and y (j, column) in the matrix.
The Actor object holds the slot, and calculates its position in the screen with the formulas above.

Another question: what are float x and float y in the dragStart method?

**UPDATE**

The correct formula for y is:

```
y = Constants.APP_HEIGHT - Constants.VERTICAL_OFFSET - (Constants.TILE_SIZE * slot.getX());
```

But the dragStart still does not work. It is totally out of phase.
The dragging does not start when i click on the actor, but if i click on an area in the top-right corner of the screen.

**UPDATE 2**

The problem is the positioning of the Table. It is totally messed up.

**UPDATE 3**

With table.setDebug(true) i verified that the table is at the correct position. So... i really don't know what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

For drag and drop i implemented as follows:

```
myActor.addListener(new DragListener(){
public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer){
myActor.moveBy(x-firstItem.getWidth()/2,y-firstItem.getHeight()/2);}});
```